# car needing a jump if it sits for a few days without cranking it

Tags: starting

I took my ford explorer to Autozone the test says the battery is good but the starter is failing in a few days it sat for 2 days and needed a jump, does that mean the starter will go out soon?

Comment: Could be starter, could be battery, could be alternator - mechanic will be able to tell you better than the Internet

Comment: I read once (IIRC, in a AAA 'tip sheet) that a key fob left too close to a car can drain the battery.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like something is draining the battery between starts, or the alternator is failing.  Normally when the car is off the battery should read 12.6 volts across the terminals.  While the car is running, that should go up to somewhere between 13.5 and 14.7 volts.

So to answer your question, no I don't believe the problem has anything to do with your starter.  I would first suspect the battery, but if that was load tested and ok, next suspect would be the alternator.  Check the voltage across the battery while the car is running.  If it's under 13.5 volts I'd say the alternator is bad.  If all that checks out ok, then you have something draining the battery while the car is off.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a [battery drain test](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/battery-dead-morning/).